# Ordered fields dense in their real closure.

Tags: field-theory

I was reading the section on real closed fields in Jacobson's Basic Algebra II and came across a theorem (Hilbert's 17th problem) which assumed as a hypothesis that some field F is dense in its real closure.

Does anyone know any examples of ordered fields that are not dense in their real closures?

Comment: I have found an example in the following paper:http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206130196

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about rational functions $F = \mathbb R(x)$, where $x > r$ for all real $r$.  The real closure contains $\sqrt{x}$, but the interval $(\sqrt{x}-1, \sqrt{x}+1)$ is disjoint from $F$.